# Avoid Nesting If Statements? (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, nested

I got the idea for this guessing game from a book, Invent With Python. I didn't like that the original script didn't cover the possibilities of re-guessing a number or incorrectly using a number not in 1 - 20, so I modified it. The program works great, however, I'm just wrapping my head around if/elif/else code blocks.

I'd like to rewrite the script without having to nest and if inside of an if. I can't even begin to wrap my head around how to do that. Can anyone please help me--just one example of how this program could work without nesting would be great!

Here's the little script in its entirety:

```
from random import randint
from sys import exit
name = raw_input("Hello! What's your name? ")
print "Well %s, I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 20." % name
print "Since I'm a benevolent computer program, I'll give you 6 guesses."
secret_number = randint(1, 20)

guesses_left = 6
already_guessed = []

while guesses_left > 0:
    try:
        guess = int(raw_input("Take a guess: "))

        if guess >= 1 and guess <= 20 and guess not in already_guessed:
            already_guessed.append(guess)
            guesses_left -= 1

            if guess == secret_number:
                print "You win! %d was my secret number!" % secret_number
                exit(0)
            elif guess < secret_number:
                print "Your guess is too low!"
            elif guess > secret_number:
                print "Your guess is too high!"

        elif guess in already_guessed:
            print "You already guessed that!"

        else:
            print "Not a number between 1 - 20!"
            print "Please try again!"

        print "You have %d guesses left!" % guesses_left

    except ValueError:
        print "Invalid input! Please try again!"
```

Comment: You can make use of [the `continue` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops), which will also help unnest everything but the input from the `try`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try it like this, using `continue` to exit the current iteration of the loop and start again at the top of the loop.

You also had a logic bug here:

```
if guess <= 1 and guess >= 20 and guess not in already_guessed:
```

A number cannot possibly be both less than or equal to 1, and greater than or equal to 20. Your `and` should have been an `or` like this:

```
if (guess <= 1 or guess >= 20) and guess not in already_guessed:
```

Or simpler:

```
if 1 <= guess <= 20 and guess not in already_guessed:
```

Also, keep your `try/except` only around the things that can actually raise an exception (or shouldn't happen if an exception occurs:

```
from random import randint
import sys

name = raw_input("Hello! What's your name? ")
print "Well {}, I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 20.".format(name)
print "Since I'm a benevolent computer program, I'll give you 6 guesses."

secret_number = randint(1, 20)
guesses_left = 6
already_guessed = []

while guesses_left > 0:
    print "You have {} guesses left!".format(guesses_left)

    try:
        guess = int(raw_input("Take a guess: "))
    except ValueError:
        print "Invalid input! Please try again!\n"
        continue

    # If the number is not between 1 and 20...
    if not (1 <= guess <= 20):
        print "Not a number between 1 - 20!"
        print "Please try again!\n"
        continue

    if guess in already_guessed:
        print "You already guessed that!\n"
        continue

    guesses_left -= 1
    already_guessed.append(guess)

    if guess == secret_number:
        print "You win! {} was my secret number!".format(secret_number)
        sys.exit(0)
    elif guess < secret_number:
        print "Your guess is too low!\n"
    elif guess > secret_number:
        print "Your guess is too high!\n"
```

Here's an example run:

```
Hello! What's your name? :)
Well :), I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 20.
Since I'm a benevolent computer program, I'll give you 6 guesses.
You have 6 guesses left!
Take a guess: 2
Your guess is too low!

You have 5 guesses left!
Take a guess: 2
You already guessed that!

You have 5 guesses left!
Take a guess: 3
Your guess is too low!

You have 4 guesses left!
Take a guess: 7
Your guess is too high!

You have 3 guesses left!
Take a guess: 5
Your guess is too high!

You have 2 guesses left!
Take a guess: 4
You win! 4 was my secret number!
```

Comment: I liked this one the best, thank you! I especially liked the pointer on the try/except block--I must have misunderstood the on line python documentation about the try/except block--it looked like everything needed to be nested inside of it.

Comment: No problem, glad to help :) Yeah, think of `try: ... except: ...` as "run the code in this block, and if any of the code inside this block fails, immediately jump to the code in the `except:` and run it". So since the `except:` (in my example above) does a `continue`, the rest of the code in the loop will never execute. The code in the rest of the loop will never raise a `ValueError`. Sometimes, you actually do want to put code that won't raise an error inside the `try:` block, for example if you can't `continue`, `break`, or `return`, and you don't want the code to continue executing.

Comment: Also if this solves your problem, please click the checkmark next to the answer to mark the question as resolved :)  Thanks!

Comment: Just hit the check button; again thanks! Also, the logic bug wasn't in my original script but an editing error here, one that I fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the nested if statements to elif like so:

```
from random import randint
from sys import exit
name = raw_input("Hello! What's your name? ")
print "Well %s, I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 20." % name
print "Since I'm a benevolent computer program, I'll give you 6 guesses."
secret_number = randint(1, 20)

guesses_left = 6
already_guessed = []

while guesses_left > 0:
    try:
        guess = int(raw_input("Take a guess: "))

        if guess <= 1 and guess >= 20 and guess not in already_guessed:
            already_guessed.append(guess)
            guesses_left -= 1

        elif guess == secret_number:
            print "You win! %d was my secret number!" % secret_number
            exit(0)
        elif guess < secret_number:
            print "Your guess is too low!"
        elif guess > secret_number:
            print "Your guess is too high!"

        elif guess in already_guessed:
            print "You already guessed that!"

        else:
            print "Not a number between 1 - 20!"
            print "Please try again!"

        print "You have %d guesses left!" % guesses_left

    except ValueError:
        print "Invalid input! Please try again!"
```

This would be simplest way i see to solve your dilema

Comment: This fundamentally changes the control flow of the program.